# Why date value added from Java to SQLite database in Android is always null?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am absolute beginner to Android. I have a problem with working with date in Android. Now I am inserting a value from EditText field to a SQLite table column that is date database date. It is always null when it is added to database. What is wrong with my code?

My DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todo.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "task";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String COLUMN_DATE ="date";
    private static final String COLUMN_DONE = "done";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COLUMN_DESCRIPTION+" TEXT,"+
    COLUMN_DATE+" DATE,"+COLUMN_DONE+" BOOLEAN)";
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public  void insertTask(Task task)
    {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,task.getDescription());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE,task.getDate().toString());
        values.put(COLUMN_DONE,Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

This is my save method in Fragment

```
public void saveTask()
    {
        String description = tfDescription.getText().toString();
        String date = tfDate.getText().toString();

        if(description.isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Description is required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(date.isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Date is required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(description.length()<getResources().getInteger(R.integer.min_description_length))
        {
            String minChar = String.valueOf(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.min_description_length));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Description should be minium "+minChar+" characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            //check date
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            boolean parseOk = false;
            Date taskDate = new Date();
            try{
                taskDate = format.parse(date);
                Task task = new Task();
                task.setDescription(description);
                task.setDate(taskDate);
                dbHelper.insertTask(task);
                parseOk = true;
            }
            catch(ParseException e)
            {
                parseOk = false;
            }

            if(parseOk)
            {
                //insert task to database
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Task saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Invalid date format",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my Task class

```
public class Task {
    private int Id;
    private String Description;
    private java.util.Date TaskDate;
    private boolean Done;

    public void setId(int Id)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public void setDescription(String Description)
    {
        this.Description = Description;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.Description;
    }

    public void setDate(Date taskDate)
    {
        this.TaskDate = taskDate;
    }

    public Date getDate(){
        return this.TaskDate;
    }

    public void setDone(Boolean done)
    {
        this.Done = done;
    }

    public Boolean getDone()
    {
        return this.Done;
    }
}
```

This is my complete DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todo.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "task";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String COLUMN_DATE ="date";
    private static final String COLUMN_DONE = "done";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COLUMN_DESCRIPTION+" TEXT,"+
    COLUMN_DATE+" DATE,"+COLUMN_DONE+" BOOLEAN)";
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public  void insertTask(Task task)
    {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,task.getDescription());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE,task.getDate().toString());
        values.put(COLUMN_DONE,Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Why is my date value always null in database? The input format of the text field is MM/dd/yyyy for date.

Comment: Could you provide CREATE TABLE script for your table? also there is a better way to save data in database as milliseconds

Comment: Yes. I just updated my question by adding complete database helper class

Comment: I suggest you read SQLite documentation and specially type formats.

Comment: I would recomment to store dates as `long` in SQLite, it is small and simple. Strings are far too large. Use `Date.getTime()`

Comment: Thanks. I am absolute beginner,  I will do it

Comment: Here you can find a great tutorial on using SQLite database in android. http://www.startingandroid.com/how-to-use-sqlite-database-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue once, and I was crazy, my particular problem was the format of the Date.
First of all check again this line, and make sure it have getting values:
String date = tfDate.getText().toString();

If is right, format the Date to this "yyyy-MM-dd" before insert into the database.

Something like that (Inside Task class):

```
public String getDateStr()
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date = dateFormat.format(this.TaskDate);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is working. Why Sqlite do not know the format like mm/dd/yyyy that is working with php with MySq,l or .NET with MsSql ?

Comment: You should read the doc: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html or this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17227209/748524

Comment: This is not working properly. Sorry ! It inserted the date but.

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many ways. I tried to insert date by formatting to yyyy-MM-dd. But it is not working properly.

> The best way to do it are:

1- Convert the data type of taskDate property of Task class to String whereas the data type for that in the database is Date. But it is a recommanded way. It works perfect.

2- Store the date as BIGINT in database. So the data type for property of Task class will be Long. This is also recommaned way.

> I used the first option.