# Android SQLite query by date string

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve a list of Fixtures from my SQLite database. The dates are stored as strings like "2017-03-01 10:00:00". Here is the code to find fixtures within a date range:

```
 public static ArrayList<Fixture> getSavedFixtures(Context context, String date) {
    UltraDbHelper mDbHelper = new UltraDbHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Fixture> fixtures = new ArrayList<>();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + FixtureEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + FixtureEntry.COLUMN_FIXTURE_DATE + " BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-10 23:00:59'";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FixtureEntry.COLUMN_FIXTURE_ID);
    int dateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FixtureEntry.COLUMN_FIXTURE_DATE);
    int statusColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FixtureEntry.COLUMN_FIXTURE_STATUS);
    int homeTeamColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FixtureEntry.COLUMN_FIXTURE_HOME_TEAM);
    int awayTeamColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FixtureEntry.COLUMN_FIXTURE_AWAY_TEAM);
    int homeGoalsColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FixtureEntry.COLUMN_FIXTURE_BOME_GOALS);
    int awayGoalsColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FixtureEntry.COLUMN_FIXTURE_AWAY_GOALS);
    int competitionColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FixtureEntry.COLUMN_FIXTURE_COMPETITION);


    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Fixture item = new Fixture();
        item.setFixtureId(cursor.getString(idColumnIndex));
        item.setDate(cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex));
        item.setStatus(cursor.getString(statusColumnIndex));
        item.setHomeTeam(cursor.getString(homeTeamColumnIndex));
        item.setAwayTeam(cursor.getString(awayTeamColumnIndex));
        item.setHomeGoals(cursor.getString(homeGoalsColumnIndex));
        item.setAwayGoals(cursor.getString(awayGoalsColumnIndex));
        item.setCompetition(cursor.getString(competitionColumnIndex));
        fixtures.add(item);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return fixtures;
}
```

But it returns 0 fixtures. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: To ask the obvious, does running the raw query in SQLite turn up any records?

Comment: the string are not only date it's date and time

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen selecting all from the table returns 100s of fixtures

Comment: @Lokesh is there something I need to change then?

Comment: SQLite does not have separate storage class for storing dates, but it is capable of storing dates as text, real or integer values.

Comment: @Lokesh is there another way I can query specific dates then?

Comment: There is already question asked for this on SO. Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227110/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-datetime-type-in-sqlite